# Kendo grid column filter message: no data found

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possilbe to show a custom message (or at least localized) when a filter does not find any data.

[image]

Comment: For grid: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/norecords For dropdown: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/configuration/nodatatemplate

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is nothing available in the grid configuration options (there is a no data template but that is for no records in the grid, not no records in a filter). However you can add a databound event handler to your grid (which fires once the grid has been rendered), find the filters with jquery selectors, get hold of references to the widgets that are bound to those filters and use the setOptions() function on them to set their no data templates.

```
dataBound:function(){
    var filterCells = $(".k-filter-row").find("input");
    filterCells.each(function(idx,cell){
        if($(cell).data("role") == "combobox"){
            var combo = $(cell).data("kendoComboBox")
            combo.setOptions({noDataTemplate: "Nothing Found"})
        }
        if ($(cell).data("role")== "autocomplete"){
            var autocomplete =  $(cell).data("kendoAutoComplete")
            autocomplete.setOptions({noDataTemplate: "Nothing Found"})
        }
    })
},
```

Code taken from this telerik forum page: https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-dropdown-filter-nodatatemplate-localization-without-custom-filter